# printStars method with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Here are my instructions:
Write a **recursive method** called `printStar(int n)` which will print the following when n=4:

```
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
```

This is what I did so far:

```
public class Stars{
   public static void main (String[] args){
      printStars(4);
   }

   public static void printStars(int count){
      if (count==0){
         System.out.println("");
      }
      else{
         System.out.print("*");
         printStars(count-1);
      }
   }
}
```

My attempt only prints one line of the given number of stars. I don't know how to print multiple lines with only one call of the method. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This one uses tail recursion, is split into helper function, and uses loop only to get the character as required.

```
public class JavaR {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(star(4, new StringBuilder()));
   }

  public static StringBuilder star(int times, StringBuilder builder) {
    return getStars(times, builder, times);
  }

  public static StringBuilder getStars(int currentIteration, StringBuilder builder, int times) {
      if (currentIteration < -1 * times) return builder;
      else if (currentIteration != 0) {
        builder.append(getNTimes(Math.abs(currentIteration)));
        return getStars(currentIteration - 1, builder, times);
      } else {
        return getStars(currentIteration - 1, builder, times);
      }
  }

  public static String getNTimes(int count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        builder.append("*");
    }
    return builder.append("\n").toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a limited solution for `count = 4` only

Comment: You can configure it to the number of times

Answer (score 0):

Your program is incorrect, see the below program and analyze it -

```
public class Stars{
   public static void main (String[] args){
      printStars(4);
   }

   public static void printStars(int count){
      if (count==0){
        // System.out.println("");
      }
      else{
          int tempCount = count;
          while(tempCount>0){
              System.out.print("*");
              tempCount--;
          }
         System.out.println();

         printStars(count-1);

         while(tempCount<count){
          System.out.print("*");
          tempCount++;
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

**Explanation** - I am using two while loops to print stars, first to print the start in asc order and second to print in reverse order. Using variable `tempCount` to get the current counter.

Comment: I would remove the empty `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void printStars(int count){
    if (count == 0){
        return;
    }
    printStarNTimes(count);
    printStars(count-1);
    printStarNTimes(count);
}
private static void printStarNTimes(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Logic is in printing star `count` times in the current call and when the recursive call returns.

Answer (score 0):

The method needs information about the max number of `*`, as well as direction (is number of `*` increasing or decreasing)
Since the requested method signature includes only one argument, you have a few alternatives to define the additional needed information:
Use a partially recursive method like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362660/3992939) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362572/3992939) answers, or use a helper method:

```
public static void printStars(int count){

    printStars(count, count, -1);
}

public static void printStars(int count , int max, int increment){

    for(int i =0; i< count; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    count += increment;
    if(count ==0 ) { //lower limit reached 
        increment = -increment;
    }else {
        System.out.println(""); 
    }

    if (count > max){ //upper limit reached 
        return;
    }
    printStars(count, max, increment);
}
```